# Putting text over image and then with ajax/jquery change text on image

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to open my own resturaunt and I have started working on my menu which will be published online.

I have an image of a resturaunt menu (looks exactly as you would expect) and its on my webpage. I would like to put text over this image so that the menu image is in the background.

I have set up two Arrow images at the bottom of the page that when clicked will either take the user to the next page of the menu or previous page. Now I am aware that I will do this part with ajax and that that I will use jquery functions such as fade in/fade out for the next page but I have no idea how to reload text (or even show text for that matter) onto my menu image.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas, it would be well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the image as the background of your page and simply dispay the text above that. That is way easier than changing the actual image…

You might not even need ajax for that since your menu probably doesn't change that frequently (even if you update it daily you should be more than fine without ajax). Just use jQuery to show the content of the page you want and hide the content of the other pages.

You could look at [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to give you a starting point on how to do it. But thats probably not exactly what you are looking for. Showing and hiding the content you want using plain jQuery can work just as well.

You will have to learn jQuery (and a bit of JavaScript for that matter) to do this, though.